# What does this mean in lme4: function 'dataptr' not provided by package 'Rcpp'

Tags: r, lme4, lmer

I'm  trying to do LMM using lme4, and this message pops up:

Error in initializePtr() : 
  function 'dataptr' not provided by package 'Rcpp'

What should I do?

Comment: Reinstall Rcpp and lme4

Comment: ... and perhaps RcppEigen (after Rcpp and before lme4)

Comment: Thanks very much for the reply. I now changed the new version of R into the old version and this function works fine on the old version.

Comment: Just reinstalling Rcpp worked for me

Comment: Ran into this problem while using the `bobyqa` optimizer. Reinstalling `minqa` (which provides the currently used implementation though [this is expected to change](https://github.com/lme4/lme4/issues/98)) seems to fix this problem.

Answer (score 4):

After a while, I got it.

1) Reinstall the latest version of Rcpp is the solution.

2) If you are not using lme4, but you also have this problem ("function 'dataptr' not provided by package 'Rcpp'") in combination with dyn.load(), it might be worth noting do not forget to include

> library(Rcpp)

or

> require(Rcpp)

on your code before

> dyn.load("your_shared_lib.so")

Source:
[building_shared_libs_with_Rcpp](https://www.mail-archive.com/rcpp-devel@lists.r-forge.r-project.org/msg06954.html)

Comment: why are you doing `dyn.load()`? Is this a solution to the error in a different context? (You shouldn't need `dyn.load()` if you're using `lme4` ...)

Comment: But I ended up in this question using google looking for a solution for " function 'dataptr' not provided by package 'Rcpp'", So I guess more people will end up here also when building their shared libraries

Comment: OK, then, it would be good to make that clearer in your answer.  There was an answer from Florian Hartig that was converted to a comment because it was so short (see above) ...