# Register C++ version of Rcpp function and use it within the other Rcpp function in a new package

Tags: rcpp, rcpp11

I have a package **hpa** that has some functions written in **Rcpp**. I want to use some of these functions within my **new** R-package. It is necesseraly to use this functions in "Rcpp form" in order to avoid perfomance penalty so I can't to export them in a usual way.

I have found a [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50128807/function-not-provided-by-package). Following the answer of Dirk Eddelbuettel I have investigated [this file](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rapiserialize/blob/master/src/init.c) and written the following code (within **init.c** file that has been placed in the **src** folder) in hope to make **polynomialIndex** function (from hpa package) become available (in Rcpp i.e. C++ form) for Rcpp functions of other pacakges (including my new one):

```
#include <Rconfig.h>
#include <Rinternals.h>
#include <R_ext/Rdynload.h>
#include "polynomialIndex.h"

/* definition of functions provided for .Call()             */
static const R_CallMethodDef callMethods[] = {
    { "polynomialIndex", (DL_FUNC) &polynomialIndex, 1 },
    { NULL, NULL, 0 }
};

/* functions being called when package is loaded -- used to register    */
/* the functions we are exporting here                  */
void R_init_RApiSerialize(DllInfo *info) {

    /* used by external packages linking to internal serialization code from C */
    R_RegisterCCallable("hpa", "polynomialIndex", 
                        (DL_FUNC) &polynomialIndex);

    R_registerRoutines(info,
                       NULL,        /* slot for .C */
                       callMethods,     /* slot for .Call */
                       NULL,            /* slot for .Fortran */
                       NULL);       /* slot for .External */

    R_useDynamicSymbols(info, TRUE);    /* controls visibility */ 
}
```

Unfortenatelly when I am trying to build **hpa** package the following **error message** arise:

```
/mingw64/bin/gcc  -I"C:/R/R-41~1.0/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'C:/R/R-4.1.0/library/Rcpp/include' -I'C:/R/R-4.1.0/library/RcppArmadillo/include' -I'C:/R/R-4.1.0/library/RcppParallel/include'        -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c init.c -o init.o
In file included from C:/R/R-4.1.0/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/r/headers.h:66,
                 from C:/R/R-4.1.0/library/Rcpp/include/RcppCommon.h:30,
                 from C:/R/R-4.1.0/library/RcppArmadillo/include/RcppArmadilloForward.h:26,
                 from C:/R/R-4.1.0/library/RcppArmadillo/include/RcppArmadillo.h:31,
                 from polynomialIndex.h:4,
                 from init.c:4:
C:/R/R-4.1.0/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/platform/compiler.h:100:10: fatal error: cmath: No such file or directory
 #include <cmath>
          ^~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [C:/R/R-41~1.0/etc/x64/Makeconf:238: init.o] Error 1
```

It seems to be associated with the fact that **polynomialIndex.h** file includes <RcppArmadillo.h>. The file itself looks as follows:

```
#ifndef hpa_polynomialIndex_H
#define hpa_polynomialIndex_H

#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace RcppArmadillo;

NumericMatrix polynomialIndex(NumericVector pol_degrees,
                              bool is_validation);

String printPolynomial(NumericVector pol_degrees, 
                       NumericVector pol_coefficients,
                       bool is_validation);

#endif
```

Then I have tried to remove **polynomialIndex.h** from **init.c** and to declare **polynomialIndex** directly inside **init.c** file. Unfortunatelly it results into the other **error message**:

```
/mingw64/bin/gcc  -I"C:/R/R-41~1.0/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'C:/R/R-4.1.0/library/Rcpp/include' -I'C:/R/R-4.1.0/library/RcppArmadillo/include' -I'C:/R/R-4.1.0/library/RcppParallel/include'        -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c init.c -o init.o
** using staged installation
** libs
/mingw64/bin/g++ -std=gnu++11 -shared -s -static-libgcc -o hpa.dll tmp.def ParallelFunctions.o RcppExports.o hpaBinary.o hpaML.o hpaMain.o hpaSelection.o hpaValidation.o init.o normalMoments.o polynomialIndex.o spline.o -LC:/R/R-41~1.0/bin/x64 -lRlapack -LC:/R/R-41~1.0/bin/x64 -lRblas -lgfortran -lm -lquadmath -LC:/R/R-41~1.0/bin/x64 -lR
C:/rtools40/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: init.o:init.c:(.text+0x8): undefined reference to `polynomialIndex'
C:/rtools40/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: init.o:init.c:(.rdata+0x28): undefined reference to `polynomialIndex'
C:/rtools40/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: init.o:init.c:(.rdata$.refptr.polynomialIndex[.refptr.polynomialIndex]+0x0): undefined reference to `polynomialIndex'
```

Please help me to figure out these problems. In the end I want to be able to use polynomialIndex function within my new package. According to the information I have found it should look something like this (simplifed expample):

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(hpa)]]
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector newFunc(NumericVector pol_degrees,
                      bool is_validation) {
  
  static SEXP(*polynomialIndex)(Rcpp::NumericVector, bool) = NULL;
  polynomialIndex = (SEXP(*)(Rcpp::NumericVector, bool)) R_GetCCallable("hpa", "polynomialIndex");
  
  NumericVector result = polynomialIndex(pol_degrees, is_validation);
  
  return(result);
}
```

P.S. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20474303/using-c-function-from-other-package-in-rcpp) is also similar to this one but does not resolve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been discussed before, and I would urge you to study these other questions and experiment with their answers.

Here you appear to have a cross-over from a *C* compilation (started by `gcc`) touching a file in which *you* crossed over to *C++*. Which, plainly stated, you cannot do for C compilation.

R offers C interfaces only.  Rcpp helps you by autogenerating complying interface files.  If you want to extend/alter them you have to play by the rules.

Wrapping C++ code in (simpler, more portable, cross-compiler, ...) C interfaces is a decades old trick.  You likely find many resources for it.

Answer (score 0):

Following Dirk Eddelbuettel's suggestion I have made additional search concerning this problem. Unfortunatelly I have found an extremely simple solution.

First, I have deleted **init.c** file.

Second, I have added the following line of code to all **.cpp** files of **hpa** package.

```
// [[Rcpp::interfaces(r, cpp)]]
```

Third I have added the following code to the **description** file of my new package in order to link it to **hpa** package (I have made it before the solution has been found but in order to provide a full reciepe it seems reasonable to add this information).

```
Imports: Rcpp (>= 1.0.6), hpa (>= 1.2.1)
Depends: hpa (>= 1.2.1)
LinkingTo: Rcpp, RcppArmadillo, hpa
```

Fourth, by the same reasons I have added the following line of code to the **namespace** file:

```
import(hpa)
```

Fifth, I have compiled **hpa** package (as usual) and have found a new folder named **inst**. Inside this folder there is a folder **include**. In this folder I have found a new file **hpa.h**. So I have simply included this file into the code and simplified the call to the function to **hpa::polynomialIndex(...)**. So the resulting (succesfully working!) code is as follows:

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(hpa)]]
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include <hpa.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector newFunc(NumericVector pol_degrees,
                      bool is_validation) {
  
  NumericVector result = hpa::polynomialIndex(pol_degrees, is_validation);
  
  return(result);
}
```

P. S. It was informative to investigate the file **hpa\inst\include\hpa_RcppExports.h** to understand how does **[[Rcpp::interfaces(r, cpp)]]** resolves the problem.